# Как пройтись по всем элементам с классом и подсчитать их сумму?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь подсчитать сумму всех текстов в дивов с классом price, как это можно сделать? И как можно удалить пробелы и лишний текст с дива?

```
<div class="price">100руб</div>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
<script>
    var price=0;
    $('.price').each( function(i) {
        price += Number($(this).textContent);
        document.write(price);
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибки:

1. Результат нужно выводить **после** цикла, а не внутри
2. В цикле each `this` равен текущему **HTML элементу**. Этот элемент имеет свойство `textContent`. Если вы оборачиваете `this` в элемент **jQuery** (`$(this)`) то у вас уже нет свойства `textContent`, но зато есть метод `text()`. Так что либо `this.textContent`, либо `$(this).text()`.

> И как можно удалить пробелы и лишний текст с дива?

Если у вас всегда вначале идет число (возможно с лидирующими пробелами), а потом некий текст, то можно воспользоваться функцией `parseInt()`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var price = 0;
  $('.price').each(function() {
    price += parseInt(this.textContent);
  });
  console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
```

Или на чистом JS без jQuery

```js
var price = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(function(el) {
  price += parseInt(el.textContent);
});
console.log(price);
```

```html
<div class="price">100руб</div>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку в диве смешанный контент (цифры+буквы), то можно "откусить" с помощью split буквенную часть:

```js
var price=0;
$('.price').each( function(i) {
  price += +$(this).text().split('р')[0];
});
console.log(price);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
<div class="price">100руб</div>
```

Comment: сорри за офтоп - а можно в jquery использовать нативные циклы?

Comment: @MaximLensky, Вы имеете в виду for и while? Вполне.

Comment: нее..while наверно зашквар ..for и forEach имел ввиду

Comment: @MaximLensky, for однозначно можно. А вот forEach будет работать только с явным массивом. $('.price'), например, это не массив, а некоторая коллекция, и с ней forEach не прокатит: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: а да точно ...спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: `price += parseInt(this.innerHTML)`, а лучше float